# Optimizing Redis for hashes cache use case

Tags: redis

I use Redis as a cache.

All my data is 16 byte hashes. I want to optimize Redis for this use case.

Currently I am saving and getting hashes in following way:

```
r.set(hash, b"A") # Sets hash in the cache
r.get(hash) # if result is not None, then I know that hash is in cache.
```

Few concrete questions:

Is there a way not to use arbitrary byte during set phase to save some space?

Is there a way to configure Redis, so that all my data is 16 bytes and it is saved in optimal way?

Any additional tips are welcome.

Comment: Hello; how many keys do you have ? What do you mean by "...it is saved in optimal way" , what is "optimal" in your case ?

Comment: @Ersoy 1. Millions. 2. Taking 16 bytes of memory per entry or close to this number. Currently it seems Redis takes around 106 bytes.

Comment: You may want to take a look on this https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/01chapter-9-reducing-memory-use/9-1-short-structures/9-1-1-the-ziplist-representation/ - i would prefer hash over strings - and `exists`/`hexists` instead of `get`/`hget`